# CSS show elements below each other

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS and HTML script:

```
.chat {
       width: 100px;
       }

       .bubble{
       background-color: #F2F2F2;
       border-radius: 5px;
       box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
       display: inline-block;
       padding: 5px 10px;
       position: relative;
       vertical-align: top;
       max-width: 200px;
       min-width: 200px:
       word-wrap: break-word;
       font-size: 85%;
       }

       .bubble::before {
       background-color: #F2F2F2;
       content: "\00a0";
       display: block;
       height: 10px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 13px;
       transform:             rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
           -moz-transform:    rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
           -ms-transform:     rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
           -o-transform:      rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
           -webkit-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
       width:  20px;
       }
       .me {
       float: left;
       margin: 5px 45px 5px 20px;
       }

       .me::before {
       box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
       left: -9px;
       }

       .you {
       margin: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
       right: 10px;           
       position: absolute;       
    }

       .you::before {
       box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
       right: -9px;
       }
</style>
</head><body>
<div class="chat">
    <div class="bubble you">test1</div>
    <div class="bubble you">test2</div>
    <div class="bubble me">test3</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

But with this scripts elements are overwritten are placed on the same line like this:

```
    test1(test3 overwrites it)              test2
```

But what I want is:

```
    test1
                                            test2
    test3
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Comment: You are wrong, `test2` overlaps `test1` because they have the same classes and `test2` is after `test1`

Comment: The HTML document is incorrectly formatted and should be purified. CSS should be properly indented too.

Comment: The code is generated dynamically in a C++ file thats why the indented is not there, is that relevant for the problem I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `position: absolute;` on the .me bubbles. Those would always end up on the top-right corner of the closest parent with `position: relative;` (or the corner of the html if all parents lack that). If you use float on the elements but want them each to appear in new lines then `clear: both;` does the trick.

These are the changes to the css, I left everything else as it is:

```
.chat {
    width: 100%;
}

.bubble {
    clear: both;
}

.you {
    float: right;
    /* position: absolute;
       right: 10px; */
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shirfy/4r2jr482/)

Comment: Please note that I changed the chat's width to 100% because you had `max-width: 200px; min-width: 200px:` and those wouldn't fit in a 100px container.
Also you have a `colon` at the end of `min-width` (14th row in my fiddle), that's why the bubble's are narrow and the `word-wrap` won't work. You'll need to fix that.

Comment: While this may have helped the op, this will not help anyone else with a similar problem. Please include an explanation

Comment: Also, note that you will have problems getting .chat to expand to the correct height because of how floats work. Just add a background color to .chat to see what I mean. You will need a clear fix of some sort.

Comment: The problem was that OP used `position: absolute;` on the `.me` bubbles. Those would always end up on the top-right corner of the closest parent with `position: relative;` (or the corner of the html if all parents lack that).
If you use float on the elements but want them each to appear in new lines then `clear: both;` does the trick.

Comment: Indeed, forgot to add the clearfix to the parent. Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 2):

**Remove absolute positioning** and swap it out for another solution.

**Explanation**: Absolute positioned elements do not contribute to the flow.

The first "you" element is currently getting positioned within the normal flow of the document. But, since it doesn't *contribute* to the flow, the next "you" element uses the same point in the flow to position itself and renders in the same spot.

Now that I've explained, I'll include a slightly modified version of the chosen answer:

```
.chat {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* clear fix for floats */
}

.bubble {
    clear: both;
}

.you {
    float: right;
    /* position: absolute;
       right: 10px; */
}
```

```css
.chat {
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bubble{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px:
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 85%;
    clear: both;
}

.bubble::before {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    -moz-transform:    rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -ms-transform:     rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -o-transform:      rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -webkit-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    transform:         rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    width:  20px;
}
.me {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 45px 5px 20px;
}

.me::before {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    left: -9px;
}

.you {
    margin: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
    float: right;
}

.you::before {
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    right: -9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
    <div class="bubble you">test1</div>
    <div class="bubble you">test2</div>
    <div class="bubble me">test3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the floats and absolute positioning.

```css
.bubble {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 85%;
}
.bubble::before {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
  width: 20px;
}
.me {
  margin: 5px 45px 5px 20px;
}
.me::before {
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(178, 178, 178, .4);
  left: -9px;
}
.you {
  margin: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
  right: 10px;
}
.you::before {
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px 0 rgba(178, 178, 178, .4);
  right: -9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="bubble you">test1</div>
  <div class="bubble you">test2</div>
  <div class="bubble me">test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I omit those then the bubbles are no longer positioned on the right side

Comment: The bubbles are displayed next to each other but not below each other as shown in my example

Answer (score 0):

Change the .Bubble display to `display: block` and .Bubble::before position to  `position: relative` as well.

Inline block will place the content anywhere it can fit and since your position is being set to absolute with the previous .bubble (A.K.A test1) the next element is just going where it can which would be vertically aligned to the top relative to other elements. An absolute element doesn't affect a relative positioned element as an extra tid bit.

**EDIT**

Your min-width tag has a : at the end instead of a ; which is causing it to break both the word-wrap and min-width styling you have. This is actually why it gets so messed up when you change the two things I mentioned. You can't use absolute positioning bottom line because it doesn't work with flow.

My bad, I noticed that above I said to change the .bubble::before tags position to relative, that's used for your speech bubble effect, change the .you position to relative. Then find a different way to right align the bubble, I'll keep looking myself.

Comment: If I make your changes then everything gets messed up!? Did you you actually try that with the code I posted?